# Можно ли на одном железе развернуть web-сервер и Active Directory?

Tags: веб-сервер

Поставили задачу купить сервер физический и развернуть на нем web-сервер и сервер рабочей группы, а я в этом полный ноль, последний раз в универе веб сервер на лабах делал, придется учиться)

И у меня возникли следующие вопросы:

1)Можно ли на одном железе развернуть web-сервер и Active Directory ? И стоит ли это вообще делать ?

2)web-сервер нужен для двух сайтов компании, из этого следует вопрос какие характеристики должны быть у сервера для этих 2 сайтов ?
По памяти каждому нужно 100Gb, на хостинге один потребляет 100cp в сутки второй 250cp

Почитав в интернете, мне кажется, что подойдет сервер типа Tower, может кто порекомендует конкретную модель. Но желательно такую модель, чтобы можно было  потом добавить ей мощностей, если возрастет нагрузка.

Я вот такой нашел, не знаю вроде подходит, может кто подскажет
https://telecom-pro.ru/collection/servers/napolnye/hpe/server-hp-proliant-ml30-gen9

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) да, наверно можно. Главное понять, что такое "сервер рабочей группы" (подозреваю, что это какой-нибудь AD). А вот стоит ли так делать - это другой вопрос. Для маленькой компании наверно стоит. Для большой - нет.

2) Часть характеристик уже сами озвучили - место на диске. Но лучше взять сразу с хорошим запасом. Думаю, 2 тб на вебсервера хватит с запасом (ведь ещё и бекапы желательно делать). И тут нужно подумать - ssd и/или raid. Что такое "100cp в сутки" я не знаю. Относительно другого железа - посмотрите на свой сервер у хостинге. Если бюджет прижимает, то лучше предпочтение отдать в сторону памяти и дисков, чем процессора.

> что подойдет сервер типа Tower

tower - это просто форма корпуса. Если сервер будет стоять "у админа под стулом", то наверно нормальный корпус. Если он будет у провайдера в стойке, то там специальные корпуса под названием блейд.

---

что точно нужно определится

- Операционная система ( а может поставить гипервизор и установить несколько осей)
- Месторасположение (офис, дом, провайдер, хостинг)
- Нужна ли там будет файлопомойка (тогда диск побольше)
- Будет ли там что то тяжело работающее - (тогда процессор и память получше)

Если для домашних нужд или для мелкой компании, то я знаю о "HP ProLiant MicroServer".  Для совсем домашних нужд -  hystou (безшумный и маленький). А возможно и решение от Эппл будет хорошим.

Comment: Да, я говорил про AD

Comment: Месторасположение -офис, "у админа под стулом"

Comment: ОС- наверно Ubuntu Server Edition, но я в этом не сильно разбираюсь

Comment: файлопомойка на web-сервере не нужна, а вот на AD воззможно

Comment: тяжело работающие будут

Comment: https://telecom-pro.ru/collection/servers/napolnye/hpe/server-hp-proliant-ml10-v2-gen9-(822448-425)

Comment: Как считаете такой подойдет ?

Comment: Возможно. Но там память ddr3... Но это такое.

Comment: https://telecom-pro.ru/collection/servers/napolnye/hpe/server-hp-proliant-ml30-gen9

Comment: Вроде нормальный. Памяти брал бы побольше(по возможности)

Comment: Большое спасибо

Comment: Ну память же можно добавить, если не будет хвать